# removing params in url for nextjs redirect

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, next.js, push

I have the code below. It redirects to /home and passes a email var. However, in the address bar, it shows http://localhost:4000/home?email=steverodgers@gmail.com. How can I pass variables using react and next.js cleanly?

```
import { withRouter } from 'next/router'
authenticateUser(this.user)
        .then(response => {
          var email = response['email'];

          if (email) {
            this.props.router.push({
              pathname: '/home',
              query: { email: email}
            });
          }
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your example email param, you have to setup [dynamic routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes) and configure your [router to push](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerpush) as the email address.

If you enable shallow routing know that it only works for the [same page URL](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing#caveats).  After you set up your dynamic page you'd navigate to it via `router.push` like:

```
router.push('home/[email]', `/home/${email}`);
```